# How to register element of page in global model state in Angular?

Tags: angular

How to add any element of DOM on the page to global model of states?

For example there is  a piece of code:

```
<b>How to...</b>
<span></span>
<button></button>
```

When component is loaded I need to get access to these elements by id, or name and execute some operation over them. Hoü to bind them to model Angular 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ngAfterViewInit` method of access elements by id

```
<span id="spanId"></span>

ngAfterViewInit(){
    document.getElementById('spanId');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more Angular way:

In your component:

```
@ViewChild('something') el: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.el.nativeElement; // <= This is your native element, you can use it here.
}
```

In your template:

```
<span #something></span>
```

API for `ElementRef` is here: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild